# Save Email Password? - Is this secure?

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I have to save the Users Email-passwords in my system ( php + mysql ).

I do it now this way: 
[alt text http://codecookie.net/showcase/cred_save.png](http://codecookie.net/showcase/cred_save.png)

Is this secure? And when not what is a better way to do it?

Comment: Could you export the diagram from the PDF to PNG and include it in your question? That would make it more selfcontained.

Comment: What i forgot to say:  the first sha-1 round is in the browser for security reasons.  so my php code only get a hashed pass.

greetz

Comment: Oh ! You're saving another service password. Feels not too bad (I repeat myself : hmac + salt for your service password storing). I'd go with sha512 instead of sha1 and the traffic between you and the client should be over ssl with a signed certificate.

Comment: It's a pity that this was not answered in 4 years, I'm facing a similar problem myself. BTW, the image link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Salted hashes are one of the better ways of dealing with 'storing' passwords (you're not really storing it as such). Note that the password is unrecoverable, so your app should cater for this by having a 'reset password' function.

Comment: the problem is that i need the plain pw from the mail account. so that i can login into the mail acc an check the mails

greetz

Comment: why are you logging into other peoples' mail accounts and reading their mails?

Comment: I am not loggin into other peoples accounts but they will log into multiple of their accounts!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommand to use [hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) with a random, long generated salt. The salt helps user who uses passwords like "a" and hmac prevents length-extension attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds good to me :) Since you don't store the actual password but a salted hash this approach should be secure.

Comment: @lutz, deleted my answer, tx for your comment

Answer (score 1):

only store the hashed salted password. this is essentially the only really secure way, in my opinion. encrypted passwords can be decrypted, hashed salted passwords need to be brute-forced.

```
function salt_password($password)
{
  $salt_1 = '7a@#!P^@29g';
  $salt_2 = 'mw3*@~2%21mD';
  //whatever random nonesense you can come up with

  return sha1($salt_1.$password.$salt_2);
}

function store_password($user,$password)
{
 $password = salt_password($password);

 //insert username and password in whatever table;
}

function login($user,$password)
{
 //select username and password info from db

 if(salt_password($password) == $selected_password_from_db))
 {
   return true;
 }
 else
 {
   return false
 }
}
```

Comment: hello,

i need to encrypt extern passwords. like from email accounts.

greetz